# How to programmatically change the UICollectionView Cell location

Tags: ios, swift, cell, collectionview

1. How to change spacing between the navigation bar and the first `collectionViewCell`?

[image]

2. I want to be aligned in the middle. In this case, the only way to calculate the screen size?

[image]

Comment: 1st problem solution: uncheck Adjust Scrollview Insets

Comment: Increase the Cell size with height

Comment: @lyyapan Ravi.. 2nd problem... the cell height is hold..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to add space at the top of your collection view you can use contentInset. There are probably other ways to meet your requirement but this is the easiest way I can think of.

   collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
2. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain more?

Comment: umm.. the three cell  height be fixed..(and the three cell height is equal.)
In this case ...I want to be a cell sorting. and it has equal spacing(4) and vertical center.

Comment: huh? do you want to add same space to the top of each cell?

Comment: umm.. explain more , in the collection view  vertical..  <ex>(top)|-A-[v1]-A-[v2]-A-[v3]-A-|(bottom)  (v1..3 is cell)... i want .. the spacing equal...

Comment: Hope you can provide and show me what you've done so far. Any code you made??

Comment: Thank you! It have resolved... using the function....minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex ... the screen size, cell size.. Linespacing was calculated.

Comment: ( mainscreen.bounds.height - (statusbar height + navigationbar height) - ( 3cell size)  ) / 4 ....